# Parse.com connection lost while reachability status == 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, reachability

I've been getting parse.com errors all day long that there is no network connection, while my reachability status logs 2.

This is the parse error:

```
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}, 
temporary=1, code=100}
```

This is the code that I use to test the ratability:

```
  Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

 NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
  if (netStatus == NotReachable) {
    NSLog(@"No internet connection!");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"netstatus: %ld",netStatus);
  }
```

It is obvious that the two outputs are contradicting.

Is there a way to tell parse that there actually *is* a network connection or any other way to circumvent this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same error searched from internet and found "problem might be new iphone simulator 6" that's why I reset the iphone simulator and than it worked..

[image]

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can just quit the simulator (Alt-Shift Q) and relaunch it